# ImageMagick : remove white lines

Tags: imagemagick

I'm trying to remove white lines which cute in pieces an image.

I'm using :

```
convert input.png -fill white +opaque "#e6e6e6" -fill black -opaque "#e6e6e6" -median 2 -magnify result.png
```

to remove the background with the following output : [image]

How could I remove those white lines using ImageMagick ?

Thanks

Comment: It might help if you provided the original image.

Comment: Captcha hackers detected :-) Try to feed that to a ML software as is, having enough samples it might eliminate that noise automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the morphological operators that have been introduced into ImageMagick, specifically the `dilation` operator. It grows the white regions of the image, which is the opposite of what you want so we negate the image first, making blacks white, do the morphology then negate back to your original.

As the gaps are along a horizontal line, we want a vertical structuring element for the morphology, so we can use a vertical line one pixel wide and several pixels tall - I chose 9 pixels. So, all in all, your command looks like this:

```
convert in.jpg -negate -morphology dilate rectangle:1x9 -negate out.jpg
```

The result looks like this:

[image]